# AJAX in a calendar view block

Tags: 7, views

I have a month-view calendar block and would like to change months without page reload.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Try using full_calendar module instead. It may work better for this.

Comment: Thanks. That's an excellent tip! If You write it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [FullCalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) instead (following Jody's comment - thanks!). It does everything I need. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Provides a Views display, style and row plugin for displaying nodes using [Adam Shaw's FullCalendar jQuery plugin](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar).

Answer (score 2):

This has been coming to Calendar for a while now, and I believe is currently in dev ([issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/339279)). Having said that, I notice that fullcalendar has 666 sites using it, so it might be good to increase that number and make it less devilish :)