# Can I do a scrollable calendar/events listing with a Drupal module?

Tags: 7, datetime, javascript

I have the [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/FullCalendar) module installed, and it's pretty easy to use that to put a little calendar display in a block (making it look good is another matter).
But can I use it to make an events display like the one on [Metromix](http://chicago.metromix.com)?
(Sorry, I guess I'm too new to post an image! Please see the link above)

I can make FullCalendar display a week's worth of events, but that's not really what's happening here.  As you can see in the example, the user can scroll left or right to get different days to display, have a particular day in the list selected, and have that selected day's events displayed below.  Those are the parts that aren't clear how to do with FullCalendar (if it's possible at all).

Can FullCalendar do this?  Is there another module that can do this?  Or do I have to do this kind of thing by hand?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that you can do that with the full calendar module.

In the example link you posted when you click left or right though the months an ajax request is actually happening returning the next months set of events.

The full calendar module also has ajax support.

To turn ajax on on your calendar you need to look at a setting called Use AJAX under the advanced section:

[image]

There is a similar question, [AJAX in a calendar view block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/ajax-in-a-calendar-view-block), which may also be of interest.